# I want to create groups for phone contacts in android

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

[Want to create a new group in contacts programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134485/want-to-create-a-new-group-in-contacts-programmatically)

I referred the above link but was not able to create group.

Should I create a database such that it should show only the groups which I created.

Do we have any other way in android?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that works for me to create a group:

```
private void creategroup()
{
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
         .newInsert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ANY LONG UNIQUE VALUE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, GROUP NAME).build());

    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.